# How do I return a Label so I can use the .labelStyle view modifier?

Tags: swiftui, label

The problem: I want a single view struct that will return a `Label()` based on an enum that will allow the use of a custom font glyph as well as the standard `systemImage` and `image` inits.

I have the following code which works as a View. But I cannot apply a `.labelStyle(IconOnlyLabelStyle())` to it and that is the part I'm missing.

```
import SwiftUI

struct LabelWithColoredIcon: View {
    enum LabelType {
        case glyph
        case systemImage
        case image
    }
    
    let title: String
    let icon: String
    let color: Color
    let type: LabelType
    
    init(title: String, icon: String, color: Color, type: LabelType) {
        self.title = title
        self.icon = icon
        self.color = color
        self.type = type
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Label(title: { Text(title) },
              icon: {
                switch type {
                    case .glyph:
                        Text(icon)
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                    case .systemImage:
                        Image(systemName: icon)
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                    case .image:
                        Image(icon)
                            .foregroundColor(color)
                }
              })
    }
}

struct LabelWithColoredIcon_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LabelWithColoredIcon(
            title: "Contact Groups",
            icon: "",
            color: .purple,
            type: .glyph)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add them to a `Group{}` then add the modifier to the `Group{}.labelstyle(...)` or are you trying to add it to the `Label(...).labelStyle(...)`?

Comment: Oddly, now it is working fine as is. I guess maybe Xcode was playing tricks on me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a completely separate view, then passing properties for that view. The view is then created in `TestView` with the appropriate properties during initialization. As a result it switches based on the `Type` defined in the enumeration. If you need this to change on the fly you'll need to make it an `@ObservedObject` and `@Publish` the variables so that their states can be monitored. I'm assuming you didn't need that based on the `let` declarations.

```
struct TestView: View {    
    var body: some View {
        TestLabel(title: "Hello", icon: "square.and.arrow.up.on.square.fill", labelType: .glyph, color: Color.black)
    }
}

struct TestLabel: View {
    
    let title: String
    let icon: String
    let labelType: LabelType
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Label(
            title: { Text(title) },
            icon: {
                Group{
                    switch labelType {
                    case .glyph:
                        Text(icon)
                    case.systemImage:
                        Image(systemName: icon)
                    case .image:
                        Image(icon)
                    }
                }.foregroundColor(color)
            }
        ).labelStyle(IconOnlyLabelStyle())
    }
}

enum LabelType {
        case glyph, systemImage, image
}
```